# Why do I get a content-type compability issue in Edge when serving CSS dynamically via PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, http-headers

I have a PHP page that will output CSS dynamically based on the URL parameters, e.g., `cssgen.php?package=10`.

I then include the output as a style-sheet in another file, by putting in the following line in the header:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="cssgen.php?package=10" class="notranslate">
```

In the css-generating PHP file I have included the below headers to signify that the content delivered is CSS:

```
header('Content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8');

header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
```

This work as expected in the sense that the styles reach the page and are correctly applied. However, in the dev console in Edge, I find under *Issues* and then under *Compatibility* the complaint that:

> 'content-type' header media type value should be 'text/html', not 'text/css'.

Any ideas why the issue is raised? And how I can correct it?

Comment: It makes no sense that it should _demand_ `text/html`, for an actual stylesheet resource. Are you sure this is referring to the request for the stylesheet, and not something else?

Comment: I guess he tried a "fake" REST to generate a CSS File

Comment: Yes, I am quite sure it is the stylesheet. Because when I expand the issue it lists the *AFFECTED RESOURCES*, and under there I can expand the *hint* panel and then find the name of the css generating file under *REQUEST*. So yes, I think it is the stylesheet. But I don't understand the complaint either... In the Request Headers it even says ```accept: text/css, */*; q=0.1``` Could it be somehow related to gzip compression?

Comment: What is a "fake" REST? Maybe I should have known, but I don't... Anyway, any hints on how to resolve the issue would be appreciated. :)

Comment: The poblem you get ist that the header files aren't made fo css. An Header file is like an param list. you need to get an check and generat script for that. BTW. REST is an communication (Representational State Transfer) it transfers data over the HTTP/HTTPS layer with the URL like yours.